# Animate my <tr> when deleting a row in a table

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, transition

I'm migrating a table managed by JQuery to VueJS ( 2.4.4 )

I would like to add a small fade out + slide transition so the user understand the row has been deleted.

Here is my table:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<table class="table table-togglable table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-toggle="true">Name</th>
            <th class="text-center" data-hide="phone">Federation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($associations as $association) // This is Laravel blade
            <association-item
                    :association="{{ json_encode($association) }}"
                    :url_edit="{{ json_encode(route('associations.edit', $association)) }}"
                    :url_delete="{{ json_encode(route('api.associations.delete', $association)) }}"
            >
            </association-item>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and inside my component template, `<association-item>` is:

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ association.name }}
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn text-warning-600 btn-flat" @click="deleteItem(association.id)">
                <i :class=spinnerOrIcon></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

I tried this:

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
       <tr>...</tr>
    </transition>
</template>
```

with

```
<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 1s
}
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0
}
</style>
```

but it is not working. Why???